# SQL Server basic join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a two tables:

- Currencies1 (with 172 rows)
- Currencies2 (with 278 rows)

I only want a join that returns 172 rows but:

```
SELECT 
    Currencies1.*, Currencies2.*
FROM 
    Currencies1 
INNER JOIN
    Currencies2 ON Currencies1.AlphabeticCode = Currencies2.CurrencyCode;
```

returns 258 rows

```
SELECT Currencies1.*, Currencies2.*
FROM Currencies1 
LEFT JOIN Currencies2 ON Currencies1.AlphabeticCode = Currencies2.CurrencyCode;
```

returns 268 rows

```
SELECT Currencies1.*, Currencies2.*
FROM Currencies1 
LEFT JOIN Currencies2 ON Currencies1.AlphabeticCode = Currencies2.CurrencyCode;
```

returns 278 rows

I have no idea why this is.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicates in the two tables.  You *could* do something like this:

```
SELECT c1.*, c2.*
FROM Currencies1 c1 OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 c2.*
      FROM Currencies2 c2
      WHERE c1.AlphabeticCode = c2.CurrencyCode
     ) c2 ;
```

This chooses an arbitrary match from the second table for the result set.  However, you are probably better off figuring out which currency codes are actually duplicated in the two tables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I certainly have duplicates in table Currencies2 (all the Euro countries for example).  I understand why you join on a Top 1 select, but I had just thought there must be an easier way . . .guess I was wrong.